# How to fit a UIImageView inside a CAShapeLayer?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, cashapelayer

I am not sure how to fit the UIImageView in a Circular CAShapeLayer that I am creating. Currently, the UIImageView (imageViewObject) is way too large and is covering up the other two UILabels I have made. Any tips?

```
let imageViewObject = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
let statusLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20))
let percentageLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20))

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    circlePathLayer.frame = bounds
    circlePathLayer.path = circlePath().CGPath

    statusLabel.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds))
    percentageLabel.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), 4 * frame.height / 5)
    imageViewObject.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), 1 * frame.height / 5)  //This doesn't fit this inside
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

```
let imageViewObject = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
let statusLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20))
let percentageLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20))

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    circlePathLayer.frame = bounds
    circlePathLayer.path = circlePath().CGPath

    statusLabel.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds))
    percentageLabel.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), 4 * frame.height / 5)
    imageViewObject.frame = CGRectMake(2 * frame.width / 5, 1 * frame.height / 5, 20, 20);
}
```